# How to insert current time automatically in table in sqlite using netbeans?

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans

I want to create a table in sqlite in which one of the field is for date in which date and time of current instance should save. which data type should i use? i m planning to use 'timestamp'. how to insert current timestamp value to the field? and how to write content values for this date field?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
   CREATE TABLE `table` (
    ...
   `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    ...
   )
```